# how to use windows service in windows form application

Tags: c#, windows-services

how to use windows service in windows form application?
I am having the database table , consists of Gold, silver,etc.. Prices.
These can be displayed in Windows Form.

I want to Update those things periodically in Windows Form(example : for each 10 mins, need to update).
Is there possible way available?

Comment: You can just use a timer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Timer to periodically update the database

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); // Everytime timer ticks, timer_Tick will be called
    timer.Interval = (10) * (1);             // Timer will tick evert 10 seconds
    timer.Enabled = true;                       // Enable the timer
    timer.Start();

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Put your technique for updating database here
}
```

You can invoke service like this

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("My service name");
if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
   sc.Start();
}
```

Comment: I know about these periodical updates in Windows Service. Is it possible to Update in Windows Form?

Comment: As mentioned above, use the timer to perform periodical updates.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Forms timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).

If the update takes more than a few seconds, do the work in a background worker.  If you use the background worker, I'd wrap it in code to prevent multiple simultaneous executions.